# how to rename google mail accounts

Tags: settings, gmail

As we all know that we can manage and access multiple gmail accounts in windows phone.But the problem with having multiple accounts is that they are named as "Google Mail","Google Mail 2",etc...
But it increases confusion because we need to remember which number is for which account.
So can we somehow rename this "Google Mail 1/2/3" sequnce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Email + accounts -> Click on the Google Account and you'll find a text box allowing you to change the account name for the email account.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Gmail on a computer.
- At the top-right, click the gear Settings.
- Select Settings.
- Click the Accounts tab.
- In the “Send mail as:” section, locate the email address you'd like to edit.
  Click edit info next to the address.
  In the “Name:” section, specify what you’d like your name to be and click save changes.

Comment: Does this name get synced to the phone inbox?

Comment: That is the name the emails appear from, not how they show as accounts on the phone